# Finding the substring in a sentence/string

Tags: java

I am trying to return a word in a sentence that has the most common characters with a given string.

For instance:

#### Given sentence:

`Old man sneezed at Starbucks.`

#### Given word:

`nee`

I want to return sneezed word in that sentence.

I am pretty new to Java and I am actually JS and Python developer so I got really confused with Char array, ArrayList, StringBuilder etc.

In my opinion,

1. I need to pass given sentence into a String array
2. Convert each element to char array
3. Convert given word to char array in the same loop
4. Count most occuring word and return that index

But I really don't know what array types I need to use.

Can somebody help me out with a little snippet or algorithm that can lead me the path to solution.

This is how I started but I don't feel like this is going to help me out to accomplish what I am looking for:

```
        ArrayList<String> wordArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 0;
        for(String eachWord : sentence.split(" ")) {
            wordArrayList.add(eachWord);

            char[] charArray = eachWord.toCharArray();
            char[] givenWord = word.toCharArray();
        }
```

Thank you all for your time and attention.

#### Edit:

I wanted add another case for it to clarify what I am trying to accomplish:

#### Given sentence:

`Up to dubs`

#### Given word:

`bus`

#### return:

`dubs`

Comment: What do you want to be returned? Just the first word that contains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to return the first occurrence, you could modify your for loop to iterate over the whole words in the sentence rather than individual chars by using [str.**split()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), and making use of [str.**contains()**:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
class Main {
  static String findWordThatMatchesSubString(String sentence, String subString) {
    for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
      if (word.contains(subString)) {
        return word;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Old man sneezed at Starbucks.";
    String subString = "nee";
    String foundWord = findWordThatMatchesSubString(sentence, subString);
    if (foundWord != null) {
      System.out.println(foundWord);
    } else {
      System.out.println(subString + " was not found in any word.");
    }

  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
sneezed
```

If you do need to deal with more than one match then using an [**ArrayList**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) like what you are currently doing would be appropriate:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
  static List<String> findWordsThatMatchesSubString(String sentence, String subString) {
    List<String> wordMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
      if (word.contains(subString)) {
        wordMatches.add(word);
      }
    }
    return wordMatches.size() > 0 ? wordMatches : null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Old man sneezed at Starbucks and dropped his knitting needle on the floor.";
    String subString = "nee";
    List<String> foundWords = findWordsThatMatchesSubString(sentence, subString);
    if (foundWords != null) {
      System.out.println(foundWords);
    } else {
      System.out.println(subString + " was not found in any word.");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[sneezed, needle]
```

---

Regarding your followup question about finding the words in the sentence that have all the characters in the `subString` you can maintain a [**Map**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of Characters and their counts to achieve your desired your result:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
  static List<String> findWordsThatContainAllCharsInSubString(String sentence, String subString) {
    List<String> wordMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
      if (containsAllChars(word, subString)) {
        wordMatches.add(word);
      }
    }
    return wordMatches.size() > 0 ? wordMatches : null;
  }

  static boolean containsAllChars(String word, String subString) {
    if (word.length() < subString.length()) {
      return false;
    }
    Map<Character, Integer> subStringCharsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (char c : subString.toCharArray()) {
      subStringCharsMap.put(c, subStringCharsMap.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
      if (subStringCharsMap.containsKey(c)) {
        if (subStringCharsMap.get(c) == 1) {
          subStringCharsMap.remove(c);
        } else {
          subStringCharsMap.put(c, subStringCharsMap.get(c) - 1);
        }
      }
      if (subStringCharsMap.size() == 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "I got a new pair of shoes";
    String subString = "hes";
    List<String> foundWords = findWordsThatContainAllCharsInSubString(sentence, subString);
    if (foundWords != null) {
      System.out.println(foundWords);
    } else {
      System.out.println(subString + " was not found in any word.");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[shoes]
```

Comment: thank you very much, I have another case that I couldnt figure out, for instance if I got a sentence of `I got a new pair of shoes` and ` hes` as a given word, how could I return shoes?

Comment: That's a little more complicated I will post another example with the code for achieving that in a couple of mins.

Comment: Something like that should work basically you could use a Map to maintain the counts of characters, (There is probably a more efficient way to write that, but I think it gets across the point).

Comment: To clarify the above solution is probably not too bad in terms of performance, I get around 80th percentile in terms of speed on questions like this on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com) with this approach.

Comment: Hey man, thank you very much, it seems like Leetcode link is empty but I will take a look at it. thanks once again.

Comment: Leetcode is a website with programming interview questions.

Comment: is there a specific name for this problem?

Comment: Lots of String/Arrays questions can be solved using Maps like this. Probably a something like "Word Search".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191345/discussion-between-mr-t-and-shash678).

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a good start - it should be possible to iterate over each word after splitting the sentence and then collect either the first / all words that contain the given word.

```
List<String> wordArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String givenWord = // from user
for(String eachWord : sentence.split(" ")) {
    if (eachWord.contains(givenWord)) {
        wordArrayList.add(eachWord)
    }
}
```

This would then return a list of all words containing the given word. Depending on the requirements this could be changed to `startsWith` / `endsWith` etc.

Since you're new to Java I assume you haven't come across the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) Another interesting way of doing this:

```
String givenWord = // from user
List<String> wordArrayList = sentence.split(" ").stream.filter(str -> str.contains(givenWord)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `contains()` method of string class. It takes one argument that is to be searched in the string object. Below code might help.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sample{
    public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<String> occurences = new ArrayList<>();
        String input = "Old man sneezed at Starbucks.";
        String find = "nee";
        for(String eachString: input.split(" ")){
            if(eachString.contains(find)){
                occurences.add(eachString);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(occurences);
     }
}
```